# Is there is a way to detect previous changes in serialized hash attribute in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to detect changes in a hash attribute in my model. But I am not able to detect changes because it is serialized. I am trying to detect changes after_commit callback.

Here is the code //

settings.rb

```
serialize :additional_settings, Hash
after_commit :publish_to_central

def publish_to_central
  if self.previous_changes.present?
    account.model_changes = self.previous_changes.to_hash
  end
end
```

after updating the additional_settings hash, the value gets updated but self.previous_changes returns empty.

I am not able to detect changes only for serialized hash and array attributes, remaining works fine. Can anyone help with this.

Comment: How do you update the `additional_settings` hash? In place or do you use a Rails attribute setter method?

Comment: I tried updating by both ways, same issue occurs.

Comment: Can you please show the code that actually updates the attribute? Hard to tell what might go wrong when we cannot reproduce the issue. Please copy and paste the code that updates the `additional_settings` attribute into your question.